# get encoded data in variable with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, encode

I have write simple code where user upload a img  and it enocode to base64.. code works fine but the problem is how i get encoded code an variable ?
Here is html code

```
<input type='file' id="myimage" />
<div id="encoded"></div>
```

Here is js/jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function readImage() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var base24 = new FileReader();
      base24.onload = function(e) {
        $('#encoded').text(e.target.result);
      };
      base24.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $("#myimage").change(readImage);

});
```

Comment: Do you want to set a variable containing the encoded string?

Comment: yes i want that a variable or an arry contain of encoded string . is it possible ?

Comment: I dont understand. Why cant you just do `var x = e.target.result`?